# Error in DB when trying to generate a model Product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am going by this tutorial to create a small shopping cart system on rails:http://richonrails.com/articles/building-a-shopping-cart-in-ruby-on-rails

When I run:

```
rails g model Product name price:decimal{12,3} active:boolean
```

Then run the `rake db:migrate` but gives me the following error:

```
== 20150303175421 CreateProducts: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:products)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `decimal12' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x00000006a0fd10>/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20150303175421_create_products.rb:5:in `block in change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:198:in `create_table'
```

Any help? Can't figure it out anywhere...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As specified in [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#passing-modifiers), you need to put the decimal field description in quotes otherwise rails gets confused and generates two fields.

```
rails g model Product name 'price:decimal{12,3}' active:boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

undefined method `decimal12' for #

```
rails g model Product name 'price:decimal{12,3}' active:boolean
```

you need to pass it that way on your console: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration